# Problemas para que un icono que está dentro de un boton no ocupo todo el ancho y largo de este contentido desde código Java en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Les mostraré mi problema con la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un ícono creado desde la carpeta `drawable`(do_not_disturb_on_black) contenido en un botón, osea, el ícono de fondo rojo, el cual está ocupando todo el ancho y largo de ese botón. Me gustaría encontrar alguna manera de que ese botón rojo se adapte al tamaño del botón `"add"` verde, ese es mi problema principal. Otro problema o algún consejo sería si existe una forma de que esos 2 botones (verde y rojo) se encuentren más centrados y no tan al final. Les dejaré mi código. Desde ya muchas gracias!

He creado una clase para poder añadir propiedades al botón rojo que se crea `"Programaticamente"` pulsando el botón verde a partir del método `setAppearance()`:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button {

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setAppearance();
    }

    private void setAppearance(){

        setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white));
        getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        setBackground(R.drawable.borde_redondo);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_do_not_disturb_on_black_24dp);
        //setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_do_not_disturb_on_black_24dp);
    }
    public void setBtn (final String name) {

    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        }
    });
    setText(name);
    }
}
```

Código del `xml` donde creo el botón verde:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/lista_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Artículos"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/cantidad_productos_ventas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:drawablePadding="0dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/customButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/borde_redondo"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

He creado un archivo `drawable` llamado `"boton_redondo"` para hacer que los botones verdes y rojos tengan esa formar con un selector. Aquí el código:

```
<solid android:color="#F5D0A9"/>

<corners android:radius="20dip" />
```

Comment: Saludos @JuanPablo bienvenido a `stackoverflow`, has intentado cambiar en `setLayoutParams` colocarlos ambos en `WRAP_CONTENT`?

Comment: Haciendo eso el boton rojo se desplaza una posición a la derecha desapareciendo de la pantalla, mientras que el Spinner y el EditText se mueven una posición a la derecha, donde el EditText pasa  ocupar el lugar o posición del botón.

Answer (score 1):

hay varias formas de como controlar la posición y tamaño de un botón:
Veo que estas utilizando un Linear Layout, pero solo te permite diseñar tu interfaz a una sola medida, lo que me refiero es que al hacer tu diseño y probarlo en tu celular se verá bien, pero que pasa si otra persona tiene tu aplicación en tu celular y su celular es más grande o más chico pz solo vería el diseño que tu creaste a tu medida, no a la medida que requiere cada celular, de igual manera si giras la pantalla se mantendría el mismo tamaño de tu diseño...más no se "extendería" de acuerdo al tamaño(horizontal).

Te recomiendo usar:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

//colocar dentro todas tus etiquetas

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

- Por otra parte lo de tus botones puedes acomodarlos de acuerdo a la medida que necesitas, ya sea chico, grande, extra-grande,etc. Pero utiliza ConstraintLayout, te será mucho más fácil de utilizar y mejorar tu diseño.

Espero y te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia! lo mismo puedo hacer si aplico el RelativeLayout?

Comment: El RelativeLayout es parecido, pero incluso el ConstraintLayout  es mejor y fácil de utilizar y diseñar.

Answer (score 1):

Del método setAppearance() de la clase customButton:

private void setAppearance(){

```
    setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), android.R.color.white));
    getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(),R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    setBackground(R.drawable.borde_redondo);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_do_not_disturb_on_black_24dp);
    //setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_do_not_disturb_on_black_24dp);
}
```

agregué una línea de código que en realidad me tira error:

setBackground(R.drawable.borde_redondo);

*) Pensaba que con esto me solucionaría el error ya que en el xml del botón verde es similar, osea:

pero veo que aún no encuentro la solución.